# EPPlus: Auto-save feature supported?

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, epplus, epplus-4

I'm planning to use the EPPlus (4.0.4 version) library to export my live data to an excel sheet using C# .NET in my WPF application. My question is however specific to the EPPLus library.

I've gone through the EPPlus samples () wherein you can use SetValue to write out the values to the worksheet.

The problem is that since my application needs to write live data over a span of potentially several days(!), I want to ensure that my data is saved every once in a while to avoid loss of data in the case of an application/system crash.

Normally, I'd expect there to be a auto-save function wherein one can save the current state, and then proceed as normal with appending new records.

However, EPPlus doesn't seem to have this(?)... How would I go about achieving this?

**Example source code**:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
{
      //Load the sheet with one string column, one date column and a few random numbers.
    var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Performance Test");

    //Format all cells
    ExcelRange cols = ws.Cells["A:XFD"];
    cols.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    cols.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

    var rnd = new Random();                
    for (int row = 1; row <= Rows; row++)
    {
        ws.SetValue(row, 1, row);
        ws.SetValue(row, 2, string.Format("Row {0}", row));
        ws.SetValue(row, 3, DateTime.Today.AddDays(row));
        ws.SetValue(row, 4, rnd.NextDouble() * 10000);
        ws.SetValue(row, 5, rnd.NextDouble() * 100);
        ws.SetValue(row, 6, rnd.NextDouble() * 10);
        ws.SetValue(row, 7, rnd.NextDouble() * 78);
        ws.SetValue(row, 8, rnd.NextDouble() * 5300);
        ws.SetValue(row, 9, rnd.NextDouble() * 1250);
        ws.SetValue(row, 10, rnd.NextDouble() * 670);

        if (row % 10000 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0:HH.mm.ss}\tWriting row {1}...", DateTime.Now, row);

            //I need a way to save the existing data say every 10K records or so.

        }
    }             

    ws.Select("C2");
    Console.WriteLine("{0:HH.mm.ss}\tSaving...", DateTime.Now);
    package.Compression = CompressionLevel.BestSpeed;
    package.SaveAs(newFile); //this seems to be done only at the end of processing!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to save after every batch and open existing xls & do updates & save again?

Just like

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
```

(*plese note here that `newFile` is only variable name, in this context, it is more like `existingFile`)

you will NOT lost what you already have in your sheets, you just need to find last row to continue where you end last time:

```
ws.Dimension.End.Row;
```

As bonus, you will not block user access to file (your app right now keep write permission and block file) to save his own changes (lets say, after he add that 'free and very cool graph he want from your data' :) )

Comment: Nice... Esp. helpful is mentioning in brief how to get to the end of the already existing data.

Answer (score 2):

AutoSave it typically something for a user interface based program. EPPlus isn't.

You have to do this yourself. Just call `package.SaveAs(newFile);` every once in a while, maybe in your loop. You seem to have an `if` in place already for that.

Comment: using package.SaveAs(newFile) causes the package to be closed! Isn't there a better way possible?

Comment: Then you have to reopen it.

Comment: hmmm... looks like it might make sense to save this data to my own log file, and then once the test finishes, run this code to export that data to excel using EPPlus! :( Thanks Patrick for the info.

Comment: That would be a good possibility, yes. That minimized the exposure of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've already accepted Jan 'splite' Kondelík's answer as the solution, as it provides the information required to solve the issue.

However, I'm posting my own sample, to help other users reach the solution suggested by Jan, faster.

Basically, when re-opening a file, you need to pass the name of the file in the ExcelPackage() constructor. Also, you can get a reference to the required worksheet by passing either the name of the existing worksheet, or the index as below

```
package.Workbook.Worksheets["PerformanceTest"]
```

OR

```
package.Workbook.Worksheets[1] //1 to n, 1 being base
```

I'm posting a sample that helps demonstrate how to implement an "Auto-save" logic. Hope this helps someone else as well.

I've created a console application in C# to demonstrate this.

**Sample code**

**Program.cs**

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace EPPlus_AutoSave_Excel_Export
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo outputDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\Auto-Save");

            if (!outputDir.Exists) 
                throw new Exception("outputDir does not exist!");

            Sample_Auto_Save obj = new Sample_Auto_Save(outputDir, 50000);
            obj.ExportWithAutoSave();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Sample_Auto_Save.cs**

---

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace EPPlus_AutoSave_Excel_Export
{
    class Sample_Auto_Save
    {
        int Rows;
        int nRowsWritten = 0;
        bool bAppendData = false;
        ExcelWorksheet ws;
        DirectoryInfo outputDir;


        public Sample_Auto_Save(DirectoryInfo outputDir, int Rows)
        {
            this.Rows = Rows;
            this.outputDir = outputDir;
        }

        public void ExportWithAutoSave()
        {

            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\Auto_Save_Export.xlsx");
            if (newFile.Exists)
            {
                newFile.Delete();  // ensures we create a new workbook
                newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\Auto_Save_Export.xlsx");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0:HH.mm.ss}\tStarting...", DateTime.Now);
            while (nRowsWritten < Rows)
            {
                if (bAppendData == false)
                {
                    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
                    {

                        //Load the sheet with one string column, one date column and a few random numbers
                        ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Performance Test");
                        InsertRows();
                        bAppendData = true;
                        AutoSave(newFile, package);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0:HH.mm.ss}\tOpening existing file again!...", DateTime.Now);
                        ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Performance Test"];

                        InsertRows();

                        AutoSave(newFile, package);
                    }
                }       
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0:HH.mm.ss}\tDone!!", DateTime.Now);           
        }

        private void AutoSave(FileInfo newFile, ExcelPackage package)
        {
            ws.Select("C2");
            Console.WriteLine("{0:HH.mm.ss}\tAuto-Saving...", DateTime.Now);
            package.Compression = CompressionLevel.BestSpeed;
            package.SaveAs(newFile);
            bAppendData = true;
        }

        private void InsertRows()
        {

            //Format all cells
            ExcelRange cols = ws.Cells["A:XFD"];
            cols.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            cols.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

            var rnd = new Random();
            int startRow;
            if (ws.Dimension == null)
                startRow = 0;
            else
                startRow = ws.Dimension.End.Row;
            for (int row = startRow + 1; row <= Rows; row++, nRowsWritten++)
            {
                ws.SetValue(row, 1, row);                               //The SetValue method is a little bit faster than using the Value property
                ws.SetValue(row, 2, string.Format("Row {0}", row));
                ws.SetValue(row, 3, DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
                ws.SetValue(row, 4, rnd.NextDouble() * 10000);


                if (row % (Rows/5) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:HH.mm.ss}\tWritten {1} records!...", DateTime.Now, row);
                    nRowsWritten++;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE: 
Looks like the overhead of auto-saving a large file is extremely high. After discussing with Jan and Patrick, I ended up realizing that it would be best to write all my live data to a separate data file, and finally export to excel using EPPlus at the end of my test. This would be the fastest, and easiest way!**

**Alternatively, if it is not mandatory that ALL data should be present in one file, consider splitting your data across multiple excel files. for example, you could save 10K records per file, and that way, you ensure speed, low memory requirement, and data safety all at once.**